# Deleting a row from Sybase database with Self referntial constraint

Tags: database, constraints, sybase

I have following records in my table:

```
column1  column2
=======  =======
12       34
34       10 
-----(rest of the data)
```

I want to delete the first record, but there is a constraint between column 1 and column 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear. Let me rewrite it:

```
 (FK)    (PK)
column1 column2
------- -------
     12      34
     34      10 
(rest of the data)
```

The table has a foreign key (FK) as:

```
constraint column1 references table (column2)
```

And you want to remove the first row (column2 [PK] = 34). Is that so?

If so, **the answer is no**, you cannot remove the first row in most cases. Typically, you can only remove CHILDREN ROWS without removing PARENT rows. You cannot remove the parent (column2 = 34) unless there aren't any children that point to it.

Of course you still have the following options:

- If you add CASCADE delete on the FK, then you can delete the PARENT + ALL CHILDREN. But I guess that's not what you want.
- Well... of course there's the option to temporarily disable or remove the foreign key, but that usually is not a good opotion, since you'll open the door for data corruption.